# Using qtip2 to access different row elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, qtip2

Trying to get the second tooltip to update it's content per row.  It will show the content for row one only.

I am trying to hover over row one, column two and see row one, column one.  Then when I hover over row two, column two and see row two, column one.  etc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.qtip.min.css">
<style>
#myTable { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
#myTable th, #myTable td { text-align: left; padding: 12px; }
#myTable tr { border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }
#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {   background-color: #f1f1f1;  }
.tdStyle{   background: #F38630;  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header" >
    <th">Name</th>
    <th">Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Alfreds Futtekiste</td>
    <td class="two">Germany</td>
    <td class="three">Berlin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="one">Berglunds snabbkop</td>
    <td class="two">Sweden</td>
    <td class="three">Berlin</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {  
     $('.one').each(function() 
     {
      $(this).qtip({ 
          content: $(this).clone(),  
          style: { classes: 'tdStyle' },
          position: { my: 'top center',
                      at: 'bottom center' }
      }); 
    });

    $('.two').each(function() 
    {
     $(this).qtip({ 
          content: $('td:eq(0)').clone(), 
          style: { classes: 'tdStyle' },
          position: { my: 'top center',
                      at: 'bottom center' }
        }); 
   });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```